Laravel Middleware error: Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector given
I have this middleware in my project, that sometimes, gives me some problems on my live server, and I don't know why, but just sometimes, and not all the times that it is triggered. This is the error:
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector given
The error is triggered by the return $next($request);, bellow is my middleware:
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Event;
class EventOwner
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(isset($request["id_event"])){
            $event_id = $request["id_event"];
            $events = Event::where('id', $event_id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if(isset($events)){
                if($events->id == $event_id){
                    return $next($request);
                }else{
                    $message = '401 - NOT AUTHORIZED';
                    return response(view('errors.not-auth', compact('message')), 401);
                }
            }else{
                $message = '401 - NOT AUTHORIZED';
                return response(view('errors.not-auth', compact('message')), 401);
            }
        }
    }
}

I already changed my return to a return redirect()->route('register');, to return a redirector object, but nothing happened.
I tried to improve my code too, I changed the code to this:
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
            $event_id = $request["id_event"];
            if (!$event_id) {
               abort(404);
            }
            $events = Event::where('id', $event_id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if ($events->isEmpty()) {
              $message = '401 - NOT AUTHORIZED';
              return response()->view('errors.not-auth', compact('message'), 401); // Create response with error view
            }
            return $next($request);
    }

although this is a good improvement, I still don't know how to replicate the error, or what triggered the error.
I tried to php artisan config:clear in my live server but, again, I don't know if it works, because I cant replicate the error.
Can someone help me fix this issue, and help me find what triggered the error? Thank you in advance.

Thats not a middleware related problem it is router/controller level problem. After your middleware is finished you do some redirects at your router/controller and your return redirect(); is probably empty. Check your redirects after middleware.

Yes, was a controller problem, a redirect in a function that appears in more then one function and controller

Basically what happened was that I had a return redirect(session('links')); (a custom cookie that I created with the url from the previous page). So if the cookie was expired or if the user accessed the page directly from the url, and then clicked on the save button, when he is updating an event*, the error appears on the local environment.
*Context: i have an event management project.

To fix my problem I changed my function, I simply added an if:
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'id' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|max:30',
            'capacity' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $event= Event::find($id);
        $event->update($input);

        if(session('links')){
            return redirect(session('links'));
        }

        return abort(419);
    }

